# How can I return the number of distinct user logins over a 30 day period for any given day?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's say I have the following dataset in a table called UserEvents:

```
  LogIn     UserID
2018-09-30    1
2018-09-30    3
2018-10-01    1
2018-10-01    2
2018-10-01    3
2018-10-02    2
2018-10-02    3
```

For each day, I'd like to return the number of users logged-in in the past month. Here are the expected results for the above:

```
Day        PastMonthUsers
2018-09-30      2
2018-10-01      3
2018-10-02      3
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
Select 
  UserEvents1.LogIn as Day, 
  count (distinct UserEvents1.UserID) as PastMonthUsers
from UserEvents as UserEvents1
inner join 
  (
    Select 
      LogIn,
      UserID
    from UserEvents
  ) as UserEvents2 
on UserEvents2.LogIn between DATE_SUB(UserEvents1.LogIn, interval 1 month) and UserEvents1.LogIn 
group UserEvents1.Day
```

The above query ran for 20 minutes on my actual dataset before I cancelled it. Any thoughts on how I can simplify?

Comment: making your table partitioned would probably help, now you read whole table where you just need only past month/30 days

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and avoids doing self-JOIN in favor of using analytical function - but still can get into issue depends on your data - try and let us know

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT Day, 
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user) FROM UNNEST(users) user) PastMonthUsers
FROM (
  SELECT Day, 
    ARRAY_AGG(UserID) OVER(ORDER BY days RANGE BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) users
  FROM (
    SELECT LogIn Day, UserID, UNIX_DATE(LogIn) days
    FROM `project.dataset.UserEvents`
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Ran this on my actual dataset, and it was still processing after 20 minutes (similar to original query).

Comment: "still running for 20 min" does not make them similar  :o)

Comment: The run-time complexity I'm assuming stems from the join of 30 days worth of data for each record. I was hoping someone would have another approach that avoids that join. I can get a rough number in an acceptable runtime by grouping by the month, but a rolling monthly count would be much more accurate.

Comment: solution I proposed does not use join and rather uses analytical windowed functions, but as I mentioned  - depends on your data still can have issue :o(